# c# AR report with Photo gets distored when saved into PDF

Tags: c#, image, pdf, activereports

AR report with Photo but gets distorted when saved into PDF.

I have a report that displays all student's photo. everything is fine when previewed as a report in Active Reports until it is saved. The saved file will become a pdf file. The pdf displays photo as distorted and non-uniformed sizes. I can say that it is not getting original file size  or dimension (width & height) because some are displayed in desired size when the original dimension is bigger or even smaller, so I am not sure why it is selective. Some are displayed in desired size some are not.

I tried scaling the image before putting it in table, which displays it good and uniformed. But how come when saved into pdf it gets all distorted? Any idea how I can suppress it from scaling? thanks

```
public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
            var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
            var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

            var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

            return newImage;
        }
```

I used it inside a function liek code below

```
using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                image = ScaleImage(image, 100, 100);
                g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 3);
                pen.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, image.Width - 5, image.Height - 5);
                g.DrawString("   No\r\nPhoto", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.PointF(20, 30));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I just put a container first for every column before the image. So the image will be on top of the container. Set the property sizing of the image as FitProportional. Note that setting the sizing to "Fitproportional" will already make the dimension uniform but it will be skewed as it will follow the column size which is most likely a rectangle, so a container is necessary.